# use chroot to lock down sftp access without root owning folder

Tags: ssh, root, openssh, chroot, sftp

Everything I am reading says that for `chroot` to work with `sftp` `root` has to own the folder. I want to make it so a user can only `sftp` to a sub-directory in their home folder like `/home/user/some/folder`. Obviously ro

Comment: What is the (real or perceived) problem w/ `root` owning the directory?

Comment: If I set up `sshd_config` to enforce sftp to `%h/shared`, I want each account to be able to manage that folder when/if they are on the box instead of depending on root to change ownership and what not.

Answer (score 0):

`man 8 sftp-server`, see:

```
-d start_directory
         specifies an alternate starting directory for users.  The
         pathname may contain the following tokens that are expanded at
         runtime: %% is replaced by a literal '%', %d is replaced by the
         home directory of the user being authenticated, and %u is
         replaced by the username of that user.  The default is to use the
         user's home directory.  This option is useful in conjunction with
         the sshd_config(5) ChrootDirectory option.
```

Comment: That still lets them navigate to other directories outside of that path.

Comment: And? If you define right permissions on files and directories, what is the problem? The whole request is silly, if there is $HOME of the user, why she cannot see her files? The request is trying to solve a problem which should not exist in right design. Maybe you need another application, `sftp` is UNIX tool and let you modify files on filesystem.

Comment: In my setup/use-case, I  can't enforce what permissions a user sets for their files/folders but I still need to be able to prevent one user from seeing files/folders of another user.

Comment: Well, your original question is incomplete then. Let me guess. Do you want each user has visible/writtable only her files in their $HOME but you want to make them collaborate in a folder? Am I right? If so then shared folder cannot be inside any HOME dir and users should not use shared account or to login into other user HOME.

Then make a dir layout like this: /groupA/shared, /groupA/userX, /groupA/userY and chroot them into /groupA and use `-d` for `sftp-server` to change working dir after login to /groupA/<user>/. For stupid users you can create symlink for /groupA/<user>/shared in HOME.